# Joomla field type checkbox doesn't update database

Tags: checkbox, joomla, types, field

I have created a component. I try to store the data from a xml form into the database. This works for all text fields but the field "checkboxes" makes problems.

Here is the xml code:

```
<field name="color" type="checkboxes" label="COM_COLOR" multiple="true">
     <option value="1">red</option>
     <option value="2">blue</option>
     <option value="3">green</option>
     <option value="4">yellow</option>             
</field>
```

code in the edit.php

```
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('color'); ?>
```

It is exactly the same like the Joomla Documentation:
http://docs.joomla.org/Checkboxes_form_field_type

But if I click to save the checkbox values was not stored in database. Can anyone help? thanks

Joomla version: 3.2.1

EDIT: NOW IT WORKS!
Write the following code into the php file where the JTable was extend. (your_component/tables/your_file.php)

```
public function store($updateNulls = true)
{
    JArrayHelper::toString($this->color);
    $this->color= implode(',', $this->color); 
    return parent::store($updateNulls);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you are doing this inside or outside of a fieldset and if the field or fieldset name matches a field name in the database?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation that you provided states clearly:

> **Note**: [...] *It will create checkboxes for you, and submit their values in form of an array, **but it will not store them in the database**.*

To retrieve the values you have to do as it says in the [documentation that you provided](http://docs.joomla.org/Checkboxes_form_field_type), fetch the entire array of the checkboxes values and process them separately. Otherwise you can create individual checkboxes that will work out of the box more info [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Checkbox_form_field_type).

Comment: Thanks ilias... I have not see it!

Comment: I have changed the field type to "list". But there is the same problem! The values was not saved in the database. Do you have any advices??

Comment: How do you fetch the list items? Can you update the question with some code from the model or from where you get and save the data?

Comment: I have just changed the field type from "checkboxes" to "list". I thought the joomla save() method will do the rest... Where I have to fetch the data? The other fields like "text" or "media" or something works fine without fetching the data.

Comment: I can't imagine how your code looks like. My last guess would be that the `color` name of the list is not the same as the field in the database or the database field type is different.

Comment: Thanks for your help ilias... I have found a solution :) I have added this in my question!

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla > 2.5 you can store it as a comma separated string. You have to override your default save function adding a line for creating comma separated string.

For example:

```
function save(){    

  $data = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'post', 'array' );
  $checkbox_options = $data['checkbox_field_name'];

  $data['checkbox_field_name']=implode(",", $checkbox_options);

  JRequest::setVar('jform', $data );

  return parent::save();
}
```

Hope this help to save someones' time. :) Happy coding..!!!